# Issue with rerouting after execution of PHP script

Tags: php, html, forms, reroute

I have a contactform that is built using php.

My domain is bestsellerprime.com

After the script executes, supposedly sending any email to info@bestsellerprime.com the page should reoute back to the homepage (index.html) but I get any error. The error says:

"This page isn’t working
bestsellerprime.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500"

How do I resolve this, here is the code:

```
<div class="form">
                <form id="email-form" name="email-form" data-name="Email Form" class="form" method="post" action="contactform.php"><label for="name">Name:</label><input type="text" class="input" maxlength="256" name="name" data-name="Name" placeholder="Enter your name" id="name"><label for="email-3">Email Address:</label><input type="email" class="input" maxlength="256" name="email" data-name="email" placeholder="Enter your email" id="email-3" required=""><label for="question">Question:</label><input type="text" class="input" maxlength="256" name="question" data-name="question" placeholder="Enter your question" id="question" required=""><input type="submit" value="Submit" data-wait="Please wait..." class="contact-submit-button button" name="submit"></form>
                <div class="form-done">
                    <div>Thank you! Your submission has been received!</div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-fail">
                    <div>Oops! Something went wrong while submitting the form.</div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $mailFrom = $_POST['email'];
    $question = $_POST['question'];

    $mailTo = "info@bestsellerprime.com";
    $headers "From: ".mailFrom;
    $txt = "You have received an e-mail from ".$name.".\n\n".$message;

    mail($mailTo, $mailFrom, $txt, $headers);   
    header("Location: index.html")
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are some syntax errors in the code.

`=` missing and `mailFrom` should be `$mailFrom` in following line:

```
$headers "From: ".mailFrom;
```

Semi-colon missing in end of this line:

```
header("Location: index.html")
```

Correct code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $mailFrom = $_POST['email'];
    $question = $_POST['question'];

    $mailTo = "info@bestsellerprime.com";
    $headers = "From: " . $mailFrom;
    $txt = "You have received an e-mail from " . $name . ".\n\n" . $message;

    mail($mailTo, $mailFrom, $txt, $headers);
    header("Location: index.html");
}
```

Comment: Can you tell I was tired when I initially wrote this code lol. I'm not going to make excuses, I should have checked the code myself. Thank you lol.